# How to properly separate in different files, many methods of a class?

Tags: php, class

Maybe I'm narrow-minded or lacking of coffee, I apologize for that in advance!
I have a class, with many methods. Too many for a single file, as it's not easy to work with.

**my_class.php**

```
class my_class
{
    private $_bar;
    private $_baz;
    //...

    public function A1($foo)
    {
        $this->_bar = $foo;
    }

    public function A2($foo, $foo2)
    {
        $this->_bar = $foo+$foo2;
    }

    public function A3($foo, $foo2)
    {
        $this->_baz = $foo-$foo2;
    }

    public function B1($foo)
    {
        $this->_bar = $foo;
    }

    public function B2($foo, $foo2)
    {
        $this->_baz = $foo+$foo2;
    }

    // ... very long list
}
```

(I changed the names of the methods to make my issue more understandable, the real names are not "A1", "A2"...)

I wish I can have a file with the A methods, another file with the B methods, etc. and "require" them in the class (I know I cannot just "require"). What could be the right way for doing that?

I explored several "solutions" as interfaces or abstract classes, but I didn't find my way out - perhaps I'm not on the right track!

In the end, I need to be able to run (in different scripts, with different methods "A1", "A2", etc.) :

```
require_once('my_class.php');
$instance_of_my_class = new my_class();
$instance_of_my_class->A1($foo);
$instance_of_my_class->B2($foo1,$foo2);
```

Thank you very much for your expertise!

Comment: You could use [extends](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php). Create one class with more basic methods, and create another one, with more advanced methods, that extends it.

Comment: @KIKO that's the reverse of what I want.
Supposing my_class is the basic one.
With your advice, I could do let's say 3 subclasses : my_advanced_class_with_methodsA, my_advanced_class_with_methodsB, my_advanced_class_with_methodsC : all 3 extends my_class.
BUT doing this, I cannot call the methods from the basic class instance. Which I need (see the 2nd embedded code part, I have this in several scripts).

Comment: That's not what I said. I meant that you create two classes, where one extends the other. Half of your methods go in the first class, the other methods in the extended class. When you instantiate the extended class you can also use methods from the first class. For clarity, by the extended class I mean the class that extends the first class.

Comment: aaahhh makes more sense, thank you! Then it solves partially my issue. But I suppose I can solve it fully in "cascading" the extends? classA which extends classB which extends classC ? (dividing by 2 is not enough)

Comment: Yes, you can extend many times. However, at this point I have to caution you against this. You should extend classes when it makes sense. You posted completely abstract code, so I cannot tell why you have so many methods in one class, but it might be caused by a design problem that has a completely other, more logical, solution. It's also the reason I use comments, and not an answer, to respond to your question. It's too vague.

Comment: yep, I understand that! But the ball is not in my court for this "design" issue (too many methods within the class), I have to deal with it! That's why I asked for ideas to make the work more convenient. "Solved" thanks to you help, then!

Comment: I've got a rule, to which I always try to adhere when programming: _"Only use things for their intended purpose."_. So, a database is for storing data, not files. Extending a class is for giving an existing class more specific functionalities. It's not for splitting up an unwieldy big class.

Comment: But... you can do what you want... 

Comment: yeah, in a perfect world I also adhere to this rule. But sometimes, when you cannot reach to make the world perfect, you have to be pragmatic and find - not ideal but working - solutions!